# Listado registros únicos según número revisión ACCESS SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Estoy intentando listar las últimas versiones de unos documentos de una tabla ACCESS mediante una consulta SQL.

La tabla contiene los códigos, nombres, fechas, revisiones, etc. de los documentos. Todos ellos están identificados por un código y se va incrementando el número de la revisión. He conseguido obtener el listado de los documentos ordenados por código y revisión.

Por otro lado sé que documentos tienen más de una revisión con `COUNT` pero no consigo unir ambas consultas.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
SELECT * FROM Documentos ORDER BY Codigo, Version DESC;

SELECT Codigo, COUNT(*)
FROM Documentos
GROUP BY Codigo
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una subconsulta, en ella te quedas con los documentos con la versión más reciente (con la función `MAX`), haces un `join` con la tabla Documentos indicándole que la relación entre esta tabla y la subconsulta es el código y la versión.

Deberías obtener los datos de los documentos, pero solo de la versión más reciente de cada uno de ellos

```
select a.*
from Documentos a
inner join (
   SELECT Codigo, MAX(Version) as versionMax
   FROM Documentos
   group by Codigo
) b on a.Codigo = b.Codigo and a.Version= b.versionMax
```